# Hadoop in Ubuntu : Unable to create Passwordless SSH

Tags: ssh, password, hadoop

I am learning Hadoop and trying to create the passwordless SSH following the procedure in define in the Book : **Hadoop: The Definitive guide**

> **Configuring SSH**
>
> Pseudodistributed mode    is  just    a   special case    of  fully   distributed mode    in  which
>   the   (single)    host    is  localhost,  so  we  need    to  make    sure    that    we  can SSH to  localhost   and
>   log   in  without having  to  enter   a   password.
>
> First,    make    sure    that    SSH is  installed   **and   a   server  is  running** (I
>   am not sure about this,What they mean).   On  Ubuntu, for example,
>   this  is  achieved    with:
>
> ```
> sudo  apt-get install ssh
> ```
>
> Then, to  enable  passwordless    login,  generate    a   new SSH key with    an  empty   passphrase:
>
> ```
>   ssh-keygen  -t  rsa -P  ''  -f  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>   cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub   >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
> ```
>
> You   may also    need    to  run **ssh-add** if  you are running ssh-agent.Test  that    you can connect with:
>
> ```
>   ssh localhost
> ```
>
> If    successful, you should  not have    to  type    in  a   password.

Everything seems working fine, but it still ask for Password. I am giving my login password, which I also use for Root access. but It doesn't work at all. Please suggest.

Adding more information. I deleted old key and added new.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

My file permissions after this were

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 incredible incredible  403 मई    24 17:16 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 incredible incredible 1679 मई    23 23:08 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 incredible incredible  403 मई    23 23:08 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 incredible incredible  444 मई    24 17:12 known_hosts
```

after changing the permission of Authorized_key it is

```
-rw------- 1 incredible incredible  403 मई    24 17:16 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 incredible incredible 1679 मई    23 23:08 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 incredible incredible  403 मई    23 23:08 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 incredible incredible  444 मई    24 17:12 known_hosts
```

But even after this, it is asking me for password when I do `ssh localhost`

Adding more info output of `ssh -v localhost` asked by @heemayl

`incredible@incredible:~$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/incredible/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/incredible/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/incredible/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/incredible/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/incredible/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/incredible/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/incredible/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/incredible/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 3c:e1:36:10:30:19:b3:e1:43:73:a5:6c:76:9e:24:67
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/incredible/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
incredible@localhost's password:`

@heemayl : Following is the output of `ssh -vvv localhost`

`debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: incredible@incredible
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
incredible@localhost's password:`

Comment: I know it should do the same, but what about `ssh-copy-id localhost`?

Comment: Also you can add `-v` and post here.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the permission of the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Its permission should not be such that others can write into the file.

For example, if the permission is set as octal `666` (it is devil indeed !!), as you can all others have the write permission in the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, then the file will be ignored by `ssh` and you will prompted for the password.

Assuming the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` does not exists beforehand, the following command

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

will create the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with the permission determined by your `umask` value and then append the content of the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file.

So, the solution is to change the permission of the file so that it is only writable by you, for example:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't help

Comment: @Incredible how did you delete the old key from authorized_keys?

Comment: from file manager.

Comment: @Incredible Run `ssh -v localhost` and look for the line that starts with `debug1: Authentications that can continue:` ....what does it say?

Comment: I think it is not trying id_rsa. Can you suggest something ?

Comment: @Incredible I am not at my desk right now..sorry..I will have a look once I get back..also while updating the post please add a comment by tagging with "@name", otherwise the other person won't be notified automatically of your update :)

Comment: @Incredible I have not experienced any such issue before..please run `ssh -vvv localhost` and post the output starting from the line `Offering RSA public key: /home/incredible/.ssh/id_rsa` to where it fails..

Comment: It seems it is not trying Id_rsa  private key