# Passwordless ssh error

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, localhost, hadoop

I am trying to enable passwordless ssh for Hadoop 2.6.0. The method I tried is as follows:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I also tried adding the following things to ssh_config file as mentioned in some questions on here

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Still, I am not able to ssh into the localhost. The output of `ssh -v localhost` is as follows:

```
OpenSSH_6.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:l/78VMLSVdtD9SMx46+m4NZt4Kmd1x8I038v9ozQYbM
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/MP30589/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MP30589/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
MP30589@localhost's password:
```

Can anyone please help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I have also tried changing the file permissions as follows, but the error still shows up

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh 
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Same as  (http://askubuntu.com/questions/627419/hadoop-in-ubuntu-unable-to-create-passwordless-ssh/627422?noredirect=1#comment891557_627422). I am still looking for answer

Comment: The lines you added to `ssh_config` are actually meant for `sshd_config`, but in any case I doubt they'd make a difference.

Comment: Eeeek! Don't change the permissions! Ever! Nothing will work if you change the permissions on those files. You need `id_dsa` and `authorized_keys` to be `600` but `id_dsa.pub` and `config` etc. to be `644`.

Comment: I tried keeping the permissions the same as well. Not helping.

Comment: // , Keep in mind that the target user usually must have a password set before you can SSH to it with a keypair.  Also, reformat this as a question, not a tech. support ticket.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way to do it. First of all, to set up passwordless access, you need a target machine. It is not something you set up locally, you must set up passwordless access *to* somewhere. Anyway, the way to do it is:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ''
```

That will generate your key. Now, you need to copy it to the target machine:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remote.com
```

Once you've done that, you'll be able to log into `remote.com` with no password.

Comment: I tried that initially but it keeps on asking for a password (which I don't have)

Comment: @sgp sure you do. It's your password for the machine you're trying to connect to. If you don't have one, then you don't have access to the target machine and, obviously,  you can't set up passwordless access.

Comment: But the method I'm trying is basically adding the public keys to the authorized ones. Don't you think this should work too? For some weird reason, the service doesn't check the keys, I guess

Comment: @sgp what are you trying to connect to? Your approach might, though I doubt it since the format of the files is  wrong, work for localhost but not for any other.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to just connect to localhost. I agree it won't work for any other hosts but the thing which is bothering me is that it is not working for localhost as well :/

Comment: @sgp I don't see why it should work for localhost either. The `authorised_keys` file is a list of keys that you use to connect to remote servers. Each line has three fields: the key type, the **public** key and the user@host information. The file you are adding to it has a completely different format and, more importantly, is the *private* key, not the public one. Anyway, try again and use your normal password, that's the one it's asking you for.

Comment: I am trying the normal password. The error is still coming up. And I am adding the public key and not the private key to the authorized keys file

Comment: And the format for a public key file is same as that for an authorized key file according to these links: https://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/IT/index.php/SSH_keys ; https://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/IT/index.php/SSH_Keys:authorized_keys

Comment: @sgp I don't see that. In any case, you can see for yourself. Just `cat` the `authorized_keys` file and the `id_dsa.pub` and you'll see they're completely different. Another thing you can try is to remove the 1st line from your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. It looks like its trying that key and that might be from an older attempt.

Comment: I tried deleting the first line, but to no use. And the trick I'm mentioning of seems to be a widely used one, especially while installing Hadoop. Check this out: http://hortonworks.com/kb/generating-ssh-keys-for-passwordless-login/ Btw, I really appreciate your help but the error continues.